# проблема в подсчёте слов

Tags: php

Есть код который подсчитывает кол-во символов и слов в переменной $text.С подсчётом символов всё хорошо , но с подсчётом слов есть один баг(фича).Если я ввожу слова на английском то всё хорошо , но если слова вводить на русском то оно перестаёт работать.Можно как-нибудь пофиксить этот баг(фичу)?

```
    <form action="" method="GET">
<textarea name='text'></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" name='submit'>
</form>

<?php
$text=$_GET['text'];
echo 'Количество слов в тексте:'. str_word_count($text);
echo 'Количество символов в тексте:'.mb_strlen($text);
?>
```

Comment: str_word_count($text, 1, "АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015600/str-word-count-for-non-latin-words